# Debugging does not show current stored procedure version

Tags: sql-server, debugging, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. I've just changed the code for a stored procedure. When I try to debug that proc, the SSMS debug window shows the *older* version of the code.

What can I do in order to force SSMS into presenting the current version of the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you modify it using an `ALTER PROCEDURE` script? If so, try doing `DROP PROCEDURE` + `CREATE PROCEDURE`. I had this problem once - `ALTER` did not update may procedure to the new version of the code

Comment: Maybe the file needs to be saved first?

Comment: @JeffO: file? There is no file - I'm changing the procedure directly into the server.

Comment: @W0lf: Yes, that seems to be enough, SSMS now shows the correct version of the stored procedure when I start debugging. Please make that comment into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: I thought you had a code file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem has existed for years in SQL Server.  It usually takes a couple time starting and stopping the debugger before it syncs up with the correct version of the source.

You will also notice that a few windows are open showing the last source the debugger is aware of.  They need to be closed.  Even though it is a pita, the fastest way to clear the problem is to stop management studio and restart it.

Comment: Use DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear the procedure cache. --> Thanks due to Dave Pinal (who knows all things SQL Server!!) http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/23/sql-server-stored-procedure-clean-cache-and-clean-buffer/

Comment: Run the following two statements DBCC FREEPROCCACHE 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS  from http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/23/sql-server-stored-procedure-clean-cache-and-clean-buffer/

Answer (score 9):

Use

> DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
>
> DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

Thanks due to Dave Pinal (who knows all things SQL Server!!) [Dave Pinal Knows All!](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/23/sql-server-stored-procedure-clean-cache-and-clean-buffer/)

Comment: didn't work for me...  still offset...  i will try the drop and create route shown below.

Comment: No, this does not work for me either in VS2019.

Comment: @RikBradley try doing it in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and then rebooting your machine and see if that helps. If you don't have it, you can install the tools for free).

Comment: @RikBradley Others noted this also, but make sure you drop and then create the code in question also... You cannot always "alter" a sproc in SQL Server under certain conditions.

Answer (score 6):

I just restart the SSMS, that solves the problem for me.

Btw, I'm experiencing the same problem with SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes `ALTER PROCEDURE` does not update the procedure like it's supposed to.

I'm not sure how to reproduce this or what are the causes, but it happened to me some (very few) times.

Try doing `DROP PROCEDURE` + `CREATE PROCEDURE` instead to make sure the new version of the procedure is properly saved.

Comment: Hi w0lf. I don't think your explanation is exactly true: in fact the procedure is updated all right, it is just the SQL Server Management Studio (and the underlying debugging facility) that, for some reason, doesn't become aware of that. But it simply works as expected if I do a `DROP` + `CREATE` instead of an `ALTER`.

Comment: @rsenna You're right. I had this weird problem a while ago and don't remember all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Almost 2023 and these problems are not solved.
The problem is not **what you should do**, the problem is for **Microsoft to see what to do**, **it is their problem not ours to fix**.
And this is not the only one, there are hundreds of unsolved bugs.
Microsoft keeps coming up with new buggy stuff without fixing any of its pending ones.

Comment: That might be true, *but* I would add this as a comment to the question, not as an answer. 