# SQL Server running old versions of stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have 1 user that when they run a stored procedure from a VB application, it runs an old version of the SP. By old version, I mean the version that was overwritten by updates to the stored procedure.

- We only have 1 schema (dbo)
- I checked for the same SP in any other database (including master) on the server and it only exists once
- We do use NT Auth
- I used SQL Profiler to make sure the right SP was being called and it was.
- I even tested this by making the following change to the sp on the first line after BEGIN:

  raiserror('This is the updated SP with an error!',16,1)

  return

This user does not get this error, they instead get the original error. The error they get is not important because it has been fixed but it is like this 1 user is calling a different SP.

To makes thing more confusing, we had the same issue a few months ago with a different database and vb app and 2 different users.  What we did to fix their issue is remove them from active director and then add them with a different name.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening, something else I could try instead of recreating the user, or has anyone else ever ran across this?  Please tell me I am not insane.

**EDIT**: We changed the name of the SP in both the VB app and in SQL Server and watching SQL Profiler, it does run the renamed SP but it still runs the old code that was in the SP. All code has been removed and the only thing that exists is the Raiserror...  There has to be something we are missing.

**EDIT2**: Would appear that an optional BIT paramater added to the SP has something to do with this. Here is what the SP looked like a few months ago before a change:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkLoadSomeData]
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @FileName as varchar(max),
    @OriginalFileName as varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  BULK INSERT ....
  ...Process the data...
END
```

And Now:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkLoadSomeData]
  @UserName varchar(50),
  @FileName as varchar(max),
  @OriginalFileName as varchar(max),
  @HasElevatedSecurity bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF @HasElevatedSecurity = 0 BEGIN
    ...Stick this into a process queue to run with higher priviledges...
    ...code ommited...
    RETURN --Must return so we dont run the rest of the code
  END  
  BULK INSERT ....    
  ...Process the data...
END
```

So we added "raiserror('This is the updated SP with an error!',16,1)" on the line after "SET NOCOUNT ON;" and the user still got the error about not having access to BULK INSERT but everyone else got the error we were raising.

Then I created a table that has these four paramanters in them and replaced the RAISERROR with some insert SQL. The one user gets the BULK INSERT error and no record in the table, everyone else inserts the record and runs the process without error. In SQL Profiler, all the exec statements are the same.

BTW, SQL Profiler shows this:

```
exec BulkLoadSomeData @UserName='User1', @FileName='UNC Path and file name with no special characters', @OriginalFileName='Line the other file name'
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the SP from outside VB with the same user? if so, which SP does he get?

Comment: @AdelSal, I have not because this is an end user without any management tools installed. The only way I have to call it is through VB. Unless you know another way.

Comment: Run this query..make sure you don't have "multiples".    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' order by SPECIFIC_NAME , SPECIFIC_SCHEMA

Comment: @granadaCoder - It is only in the result set once. Interesting thing is since the SP was recreated, I expected the create date to be today but it is from 1.5 years ago. Not sure how the developer renamed the SP but I am going to DROP it and then CREATE it in seperate transactions.

Comment: Sounds like a sybase gremlin has remained with your system.

Comment: Dropped and recreated, got a new create date but the user still runs the old SP.

Comment: do they have a different default schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Stored Proc code and additional information that we see under **EDIT2** we know that:

1. BULK INSERT is being called
2. "the user still got the error about not having access to BULK INSERT but everyone else got the error we were raising"

Certain T-SQL functions (e.g. OPENQUERY, OPENROWSET, [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), etc) do pre-validation on security. A User must have INSERT and ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permissions, and in some cases ALTER TABLE, in order to execute BULK INSERT. Additionally, NTFS / Active Directory permissions for the User (if using Windows Authentication) or the "Log On As" Account of the SQL Server Service (if using SQL Server Authentication) will be validated to ensure that the file is readable.

Pre-validation (or at least what I am calling "pre-validation") occurs when the Stored Proc (or Function, etc) is called and not as each line is executed. If an error occurs at this point then none of the code in your Proc will be execute, including the RAISERROR or the INSERT into the log table.

Hence, the most likely cause of the behavior that you are seeing is that the User that has the issue is lacking either a) one or more of the required SQL Server permissions, or b) the appropriate NTFS permissions, or c) all of the above.

Given that the error was about not having access to BULK INSERT, my guess is that this particular user is missing one or more of the SQL Server permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to restart SQL Server Database Engine service. 
Take a look at this SO question:
[Debugging does not show current stored procedure version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961600/debugging-does-not-show-current-stored-procedure-version)

Comment: The debugging issue is something I have known about for a while but that is not the case here. This has been in production for 1.5 years. Also, we have tried completely restarting the server with no change. The only thing we have found to fix this issue is to give the user a new Active Directory log-in. This is NOT something we are willing to do to all our users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try dropping the proc then re-adding it (as opposed to alter proc)?

Have you tried using sp_recompile?

Have you tried using the "with recompile" option on the stored proc?

Have you tried sacrificing a virgin?

Comment: Tried drop and create, no change. Will try the recompile on Monday, the user will be unable to retry anymore today. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are running SQL Profiler, do you see the renamed proc being called by the user who seems to be running the old code? Meaning, are you sure that the event you are seeing in Profiler is that specific user? You stated that changing the Active Directory account is the only thing that worked for that case in the past, which implies that this has something to do with their SID and/or Login.  Are they logging into SQL Server via a Login of the same name or via a Role?

If logging in via a Login of their name (i.e. *not* a role), then compare their Login properties with other Logins that do work. Check things like: default database, default schema, server roles, database roles.

You said that you deleted and recreated the proc but they still run the "old" code. How about deleting the proc and having them attempt to execute it.  If they can still run it when it doesn't exist, then check things like:

- Are they really connecting to the same server you think they are (long shot but can't be ruled out based solely on the info presented here).
- Are they connecting to the database you think they are connecting to?
- Are there any SYNONYMS involved that could be remapping the proc? ( `SELECT * FROM sys.synonyms` )
- Are there any numbered procedures involved (long shot but they wouldn't show up in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query provided by granadaCoder) ( `SELECT * FROM sys.numbered_procedures` )

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. 1: I do see the renamed proc being called by the correct user exactly when they run it, and on the right server. That is what's so strange. 2: The user is using NT Auth and every (normal) user is in a role and we set security based on the role. Other users in this role do NOT have the same issue. 3: We had tried deleting the proc and the user got an error about it not existing.  4: Checked synonyms and numbered procedures, we have zero.

Comment: @Steve: does this user have a login of the same name that you are assuming isn't there? I assume you mean they are logging in via an AD Group. Worth checking to make sure that the role is the only way they are getting in. Is there a way to take them out of the role or AD Group to see what happens? When they run the proc and do not get your RAISERROR, does it run the "old" code or do they get an error? If error, what is that error (you mentioned they get the "original error")? In Profiler, show db_id and object_id fields and make sure those match the proc you believe is being called.

Comment: I'm not sure yet but the issue may be related to an optional BIT parameter that is not getting passed and is not getting set to the default value (0) but for some reason it is working different for this user than others. For this user, it is not 0 and it is not null. Still doing some testing on this.

Comment: How does an optional BIT param explain not seeing the RAISERROR when it was the only code in the proc? If the proc param has a default and you aren't getting a value and also not getting the default, then the proc is being called with that param specified. You can see this in Profiler using the BatchEnd event, I believe. Can you please at least let me know about my questions regarding do they have their own named login as well the group, and what was the "old" error that they are getting?

Comment: We do not name users in SQL Server, we only create roles that AD users are tied to. The old error is not important. In the case of a few months ago, there was no error, it just did not update a new field in a table. In this case, the developer left in a BULK INSERT which we dont allow end users to do. Code had been changed (2-3 months ago) to not do the bulk insert but this user gets an error when they run this SP. It is an sp they run multiple times this time of the year but not again until next year.

Comment: @Steve: what error does the user get now? Is it possible that the user is in more than 1 AD Group and somehow coming through via more than 1 role? There has to be something tied to the AD login that is different than the other users of this system. I was asking about the old error as it might indirectly help point to the difference between this user and the rest.

Comment: ERROR: "You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement". This user is in multiple AD groups. Net admin has checked multiple times and all of the users (in question) have the same AD groups.  Please see my EDIT2 on the main post to see more info and what is has to do with optional paramanters.

Comment: @Steve: I see the EDIT2. My guess is that BULK INSERT perms are pre-validated, much like OPENROWSET, etc., especially with the chane you made to do the INSERT into the log table that this user doesn't do. Comment-out everything after the END (i.e. starting with BULK INSERT). If I am right about the prevalidation check then with the rest of the code commented out this user should insert into the new logging table. If they are then able to insert the row, have this user try to open the file that BULK INSERT is referencing in Windows Explorer. This could be an Impersonation / Delegation issue.

Comment: What does Hommer Simpson say?  DOE!!  I bet your right. Still does not make sense why the other users are OK but this will make me look at this a whole other way. Perhaps this was not related to the issue we had a few months ago.

Comment: @Steve: Well, if somehow this one user is specified as a deny read in terms of NTFS permissions on the file, then it would make sense as that overrides any grants. That is why the user needs to try accessing the file. You can also look at the effective permissions on that file to maybe work it backwards from there. Please let me know if that is the issue so I can update my answer to be accurate for the issue.

Comment: @strutzky You were right, it was the pre-validation in this case. It appears this issue was NOT related to the previous issue it just acted the same until further investigation. Create a new answer and I will mark it.