# SqlException: Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied SSMS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I am sure the solution is something super simple that I am missing but I keep getting a

> SqlException: Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

error. I am not a SQL wizard but to me the parameter looks okay. I did change the parameter and was not receiving this error but then when I consistently started receiving it I restored the stored procedure to the original version that I knew for a fact was fine but still receive it.

I tried executing the stored procedure like this

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[BHS_CloseCnt_Print_PackList] @palletid = '562992'
```

with a variable filled in. This stored procedure calls a function that determines the status of an order, if the variable I plug in and check with this method meets the criteria for the function I get an expected return.

If the container does not yet meet the function criteria, I get a null which I believe is okay.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[BHS_CloseCnt_Print_PackList]
    (@PalletId numeric)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @PO as nvarchar(50)

    Declare @Internal_Shipment_Num as numeric
    Declare @Internal_Shipment_Line_Num as numeric

    select top 1 
        @Internal_Shipment_Num = sc.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM, 
        @Internal_Shipment_Line_Num = sc.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM 
    from 
        SHIPPING_CONTAINER sc
    where 
        INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM = @PalletId 
        or PARENT = @PalletId 
        and INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM is not null

    select @PO = dbo.fn_BHS_AllPOPLTS_CLOSED(@PalletId, @Internal_Shipment_Num, @Internal_Shipment_Line_Num)

    print @PO

    if @PO is not null
    Begin
        select @PalletId 'INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM',  '60' 'DOCUMENT_TYPE'
    End
End

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_BHS_AllPOPLTS_CLOSED]
    (@palletId numeric,
     @Internal_Shipment_Num numeric,
     @Internal_Shipment_Line_Num numeric)
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @PO nvarchar(50)
    Declare @OPENPO nvarchar(50)
    Declare @IntShip as numeric 

    select @PO = isnull(sd.CUSTOMER_PO, 'FEIT')
    from SHIPMENT_DETAIL sd
    where sd.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM = @Internal_Shipment_Line_Num
      and sd.internal_shipment_num = @Internal_Shipment_Num

    select @OPENPO = isnull(sd.CUSTOMER_PO, '') 
    from shipping_container sc
    join  SHIPMENT_DETAIL sd on sd.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM = sc.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM
    where sd.CUSTOMER_PO = @PO and sc.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = @Internal_Shipment_Num
      and sc.status < 600

    if(isnull(@OPENPO, '') != '')
    Begin
        set @PO = null
    End

    return @PO

End
```

Comment: How about the code for fn_BHS_AllPOPLTS_CLOSED? How many parameters does it take, can you share the code? The EXECUTE statement you provided seems to work, so could it be the function?

Comment: Nemanja, I just revised to include the function script.  I did try adding a parameter to the function and was using that as a new parameter for the SP, but when I started receiving the error I restored both to previous known working versions but am still receiving the error.

Comment: OK, I've just run your code and it works, so I can't reproduce the issue. If I understand correctly, you are saying that this code is for the working version, but you are still getting an error as a result of your changes which you have undone in the mean time. If that is so, then you are probably getting the error because somehow the old version of the function or SP is being executed. Perhaps look at something like the suggestions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721306/sql-server-running-old-versions-of-stored-procedures

Comment: That was it.  I ran DBCC FREEPROCCACHE as suggested in one of the responses to clear the cache and was able to successfully run the SP with no errors as expected, thank you!!!

Comment: Great. Post it as the answer and accept it so it can help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure looks to have stored the cache from the previous edit I did although a known working version was restored.

Resolution for this was to run DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear the stored procedure cache and I was able to execute as expected.

Thanks Nemanja Perovic!