# SSMS updating stored procedures in debugger

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures, ssms

My problems is that when I alter a stored procedure, in SSMS v17.4, and then debug the procedure, I see the unaltered version as I step through it. Does anybody know how to force the debugger to show the new version? I've tried 'DBCC FreeProcCache' with mixed results and short of restarting SSMS I'm not how to get the debugger to show the new version.

Comment: Found the answer in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961600/debugging-does-not-show-current-stored-procedure-version). Change the Alter Procedure to 
   Drop Procedure  Go  Create Procedure  Simple and effective - big thanks to @Golfwolf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging does not show current stored procedure version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961600/debugging-does-not-show-current-stored-procedure-version)